# Binary Tree Fold Functions

Tags: haskell, binary-tree, fold

I have the definition of a Binary tree in Haskell as the following:

```
data BTree x = Nil | BNode x (BTree x) (BTree x)
```

I then have a fold definition for this data type:

```
foldB :: (x -> u -> u -> u) -> u -> BTree x -> u
foldB f a Nil = a
foldB f a (BNode x l r) = f x (foldB f a l)(foldB f a r)
```

So I hoped that I could simply make this function to sum all the values:

```
sumBFold :: (Num a) => BTree a -> a
sumBFold x = foldB (+) 0 x
```

But this does not work, and I cannot for the life of me figure out why.
The useful part of the error message I'm getting is:

```
Couldn't match type `a` with `a -> a'
`a' is a rigid type variable bound by the type signature for:
sumBFold :: forall a. Num a => BTree a -> a
Expected type: (a -> a) -> a -> a -> a
Actual type: (a -> a) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
In the first argument of folB namely `(+)`
```

Comment: The function you need to pass to `foldB` takes 3 parameters, while `(+)` only takes two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes about from trying to use

```
(+) :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a
```

as a parameter with type

```
(x -> u -> u -> u)
```

If you start trying to fit it in, remembering that `(x -> u -> u -> u)` is the same as `(x -> (u -> (u -> u)))`,

```
x == a
u == a
u -> u == a -> a == a
```

which is impossible, and where the error comes from.

Consider any of the following.

```
sumBFold :: (Num a) => BTree a -> a
sumBFold = foldB add3 where add3 x y z = x + y + z
sumBFold = foldB $ \x y z -> x + y + z
sumBFold = foldB ((.) (+) . (+))
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarity of your answer. I'm still new to functional programming and it's easy to get thrown off by the types